# Roblox hip height script only works for certain players

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a very basic script which raises a player above the ground. The script is player.Character.Humanoid.HipHeight = 15. When the game runs, it works for some players and not for others (the others stay on the game surface). I added a line to the script to confirm the hip height of each player via: print (player.Character.Humanoid.HipHeight) and for all the players it prints out 15. So why do some players stay on the game surface even when it says their hip height is 15 and other players are raised higher? Would love any ideas / theories. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some players stay on the floor, because of their avatar height, for example, anthro players are taller than normal ones, and different body parts from the catalog can have different heights and thus different hipheights. A solution is to add 15(or any number) to the hipheight, for example: `player.Character.Humanoid.HipHeight += 15`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've also tried that approach (adding +15) and once again it works for some players and not others. I don't see any differences between the players - all are R15.

Comment: Another note: the actual hip heights of the players involved does not seem to have an my correlation to whether the hip height increase works or not.

Comment: Interesting, did you put the code in a local script or a script? Is the hipheight set from 
a function that is called when an event fires?